# SQLite batch insert not speeding up with Transactions

Tags: sqlite, f#, microsoft.data.sqlite

I am trying to make a helper function to make inserts to a SQLite database easy to generalize.

For example:

```ml
  member __.RegisterUsers (users : UserData array) =
    insertOrReplace "User" users [|
      ("id", fun u -> u.id)
      ("nick", fun u -> u.nick)
      ("is_verified", fun u -> u.is_verified)
      ("is_banned", fun u -> u.is_banned)
      ("subscriptions", fun u -> u.num.subscriptions)
      ("subscribers", fun u -> u.num.subscribers)
      ("total_posts", fun u -> u.total_posts)
      ("original_nick", fun u -> u.original_nick)
    |]
```

My implementation is as follows:

```ml
  let insertOrReplace (table:string) (items:'T array) (args:(string * ('T -> obj)) array)=
    let fieldNames = args |> Seq.map fst |> Seq.toArray
    let parameterNames = fieldNames |> Array.mapi (fun i name -> $"@{name}{i}")

    let commandText =
      StringBuilder()
        .Append($"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO {table} (")
        .AppendJoin(", ", fieldNames)
        .Append(") VALUES (")
        .AppendJoin(", ", parameterNames)
        .Append(");")
        .ToString()

    use transaction = connection.BeginTransaction()
    use command = new SqliteCommand(commandText, connection, transaction)

    let parameters =
      parameterNames |> Array.map (fun name ->
        let parameter = command.CreateParameter()
        parameter.ParameterName <- name
        command.Parameters.Add(parameter)
      )
      
    try
      let modifiedFields = items |> Array.map (fun item -> 
          Array.iter2 (fun (name, selector) (parameter:SqliteParameter) -> parameter.Value <- selector item) args parameters
          command.ExecuteNonQuery()
      )
      transaction.Commit()
      modifiedFields |> Array.sum |> Ok
    with
    | _ as ex -> Error ex.Message
```

This uses Microsoft's [Microsoft.Data.Sqlite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/?tabs=netcore-cli) library

The table definition I'm trying to insert to:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS User (
    id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    nick TEXT NOT NULL,
    is_verified INTEGER NOT NULL,
    is_banned INTEGER NOT NULL,
    subscriptions INTEGER NOT NULL,
    subscribers INTEGER NOT NULL,
    total_posts INTEGER NOT NULL,
    original_nick TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

This "works" in the sense that the data is inserted correctly, but it's extremely slow and takes about 75-110 ms per record. For a single record, that's negligible, but I'm trying to insert hundreds at a time and it's becoming a serious bottleneck.

Things I've tried:

- Batching multiple inserts in each execution. This did not affect the throughput at all
- Reusing parameters. No change
- Transactions. Every source I've seen online points to transactions as the solution to this problem, but adding them in did nothing. I tried directly copying Microsoft's [bulk insert guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/bulk-insert), but to no avail

Comment: I think my problem may be related to the "insert or replace" approach to the insert. This is not an optional part of the query for my use case though, so I may just have to live with a slow query...

Comment: Have you tried profiling the code to see where the time is being used?  It may be the ExecuteNonQuery() that is slow but then again it might not.  Do you know the ratio of inserts to replaces?  If the replaces are few in number  compared to the inserts then always inserting and catching  the primary key exception and doing an update could possibly help. SQLite isn't a database I know well so this may not apply but to speed something up with transactions I'd normally be doing multiple inserts in each transaction - only one transaction for every N inserts to reduce the commit overhead.

Comment: @Jackson, yes it is definitely the `ExecuteNonQuery()` that takes up the time. All other code takes <1ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with any of the code shown here, but with the several other tables that all had foreign key references to the `User` table. There were several hundred thousand records with foreign key references to `User`s, and apparently checking foreign key integrity for that many was just too much.

Data integrity is not a huge concern for this project and missing key references are not a problem, so I decided to remove all foreign key constraints. I left primary key constraints in place, as that *is* important for my use case.

After rebuilding the database with no foreign keys, insert times are down to about 10-30ms per batch as opposed to the 10-30+ seconds previously.

For anyone in the future with a similar problem where dropping foreign key constraints is acceptable for their project, I found [this guide](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/foreign_keys/drop.php) ([archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20240320173923/https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/foreign_keys/drop.php)).